# Regex to match first slash in url to extract everything after it

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this link:

```
http://mysite.com/subdirectory/something/stuff/index.php
```

What regex would I be able to use that matches only the first slash so that I am able to extract everything behind it using the $1 or $2 variables that represent found items? So that it would return "subdirectory/something/stuff/index.php".

For example, I thought of using this regex:

```
(.*)/(.*)
```

But that keeps repeating for each slash so it will only return the last part (in this case index.php) of the url when I use $2.

The language I'm using it with is apache (?), it'll go in a .htaccess file.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Ok, so the background on this is that I have some files in the subdirectory linking to other files using links like "/files/test.php", because those files expect the other directories to be in the root folder, but on my site they aren't. So I thought of using the htaccess file to redirect those requests to the root folder to the subdirectory so everything works. And replacing all the links is not an option because there are more than a thousand of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression (it will redirect to the subdirectory stuff only if the requested file does not exist, so if it exists it won't loop infinitly) :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/stuff/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: When I use $1 with that, I end up in an infinite redirect loop. And when I use $2 with that, all I end up with is "index.php", not the full path.

Comment: I think your issue for getting infinite loop is that you need to add a RewriteCond, because you want to redirect something that contains a / to another thing that contains a /. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I think you may be right, at least partially. But I'm not familiar with the RewriteCond value, as I'm fairly new to apache language, so what exactly would I enter there? I've been working on this for 2 days now and I just can't figure out what I have to do. And besides, wouldn't $1 just return the link to my site, in this case "http://mysite.com"

Comment: If we take this example : http://www.domaine.com/dir/subdir/file.php. $1 will contain dir and $1 will contain subdir/file.php.
I can't realy help you with the RewriteCond because that depends on what you are trying to redirect to. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond and http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/iirf20Help/html/39dbb30e-2afd-4cb1-aaff-45497fe2cbe6.htm

Comment: Alright, but the request could be to any folder on my site so when I use a condition I would have to add one for each possible redirect there is. Maybe the edit in my original post makes things a bit easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: If the files you want to redirect are all in one directory (or a few at least) you can use a regex like this instead `^dirname/(.*)$`

Comment: Thanks for all your help, however that still wouldn't work, as the index file of the subdirectory isn't in the subdirectory itself. It is a real weird structure of many directories all linking to each other. The index file is actually in a directory within the subdirectory, so no required file is actually in the subdirectory. The thing is, when I put all the files in the root of my site it works perfectly, but I can't as I don't want the files to be the main files of the site, that's why they're in a subdirectory.

Comment: Hmm, is there a RedirectCond that checks if the link starts with a slash like this "/"? That way I could make it only redirect links to the root directory somewhere else if it is possible.

Comment: Can you give me one or tow example of link and where you want to redirect them ? I can help you better then

Comment: Okay, so for example there is a file "mysite.com/sub/stuff/test.php" that contains the link "/images/test.jpg". This means it links to "mysite.com/images/test.jpg", while the file is not there. I would like to make it redirect "/images/test.jpg" to "mysite.com/sub/stuff/images/test.jpg" so that it would be kind of aware that it is not in the root directory of the site. So what I'm saying is that I would like to change the meaning of the "/" character at the beginning of a url. I'd like to make it link to the subdirectory instead of the root directory.

Comment: Hmm it looks good but links still redirect to the root of the site. I'm getting close to just letting it go altogether, maybe this is just one thing that can't be solved. Maybe if there was a way I could show you what I'm doing here so that you could see if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I added an R=301 (wich tells apache to tell the user browser to redirect itself to the new link)

Comment: Sorry but still no effect. I think this is something apache can't handle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14910/discussion-between-qub1-and-yazmat)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is greedy `(.*)`. Try making the first part non-greedy:

```
(.*?)/(.*)
```

Comment: No for some reason that won't work for me, I end up with only "index.php" when I use $2 with your regex.

Comment: For your example URL, can your provide the corresponding values of `$1` and `$2`?

Comment: Well when you use regex the values of $1 and $2 depend on what is found using the regex string, so in this case $1 would match the part that is found with "(.*?)" in your regex, which is http://mysite.com in my link, and $2 would match what was found with "(.*)", which should be "subdirectory/something/stuff/index.php" in the link, but isn't for some strange reason.

Comment: Yeah that would work indeed, but only for this url. The url can be anything, so the amount of slashes could be different.

Comment: How would the number of slashes be different? The `//` refers to the slashes in `protocol://`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/)(.*)
```

The second group will contain what you're looking for